# ViewController Hierarchy - Remove UISplitviewController from stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

My app has a login view, a loading view,a split view, and a menu view.

[image: view flow]

On launch, the initial view is the login view. It proceeds to the loading view when the user logs in successfully.  Once the data is loaded, I present the split view.  On the split view, I have a menu that I present modally.  Among the options for the menu is logout.  When the user logs out, I want to return to the login view.  So far, so good.

The problem is that when I check the view hierarchy, the split view is still beneath the login view.  Theoretically, the user could create a situation with an infinite number of layered views in this way.

[image: stacked views]

How can I get the user back to the login view and dismiss the split view?

I am using storyboards and segues to get to the split view. The login view pushes to the loading view which pushes to the split view.  I present the modal menu in a custom modal presentation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            //VC1


            -(IBAction)button_click:(id)sender
            {
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                ViewController2 *viewController2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
            }


            //VC2


            -(IBAction)button_click:(id)sender
            {

                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                ViewController3 *viewController3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC3"];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController3 animated:YES];

            }

            //VC3
    // In .h file
    @interface ViewController3 : UIViewController<ViewController4Delegate>

    -(IBAction)button_click:(id)sender;

    @end

         //In .m file   
            -(IBAction)button_click:(id)sender
            {
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                ViewController4 *viewController4 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC4"];

                viewController4.delegate=self;

                [self.navigationController presentViewController:viewController4 animated:YES completion:nil];
            }

            -(void)completed
            {
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }

            //VC4
            //In .h file
            @protocol  ViewController4Delegate

        -(void)completed;

        @end

        @interface ViewController4 : UIViewController

        -(IBAction)button_click:(id)sender;

        @property(nonatomic,weak) id <ViewController4Delegate> delegate

         //In.m file
            -(IBAction)button_click:(id)sender
            {


                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

                    if(delegate)
                    {
                        [delegate completed];
                    }

                }];
            }
```

Comment: Hmm. Not working.  It clears the modal, but not the split view.  

The modal view is setup to use a notification to the detail view when the user logs out.  When I get the notification in the detail view, I am using `NSLog(@"rootview: %@", [self.view.window rootViewController]);` and it is reporting the login view as root.

I've tried with and without the completion block and both versions will not show the login view.

Comment: Give me 5 mins I will fix it

Comment: Let me know if you get any issue. I have tested in my app its working fine.

Comment: In this, VC3 is the detail view of a split view.  From VC2, I am presenting the split view using `[self.navigationController presentViewController:viewController3 animated:YES completion:nil];`  I am wondering if the split view needs to call back to VC1 instead of VC3 itself...

Comment: in DetailViewcontroller(VC3) On complete methos UINavigationController *navigationalController=(id)self.parentViewController. This will give you splitview controller navigationController  [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I will write down quickly

Comment: I have edited my answer just type [self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            } in completed delegate method it will take  to LoginView

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a navigation controller for this ViewController Hierarchy? Assuming you do have a navigation controller:

If the LoginView is set as the rootViewController for the Navigation Controller and the LoadingView and SplitView are "pushed" onto the Navigation Stack, then what you can do is you can dismiss the modal and in the completion block, you can pop to the root view controller -> which would be your Login Controller.

So in your LogoutModal you would do this on the Logout Button Click Handler:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.presentingViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

This dismisses the modal and then as soon as that is complete, it pops the navigation stack all the way back to the root view controller.